# Delta diff not desired results

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I'm looking to do a countdown in days until x date. I tried this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date = input('Enter your date: ')
delta = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d') - datetime.now()
print("We'll be {} in {} days".format(date, delta.days))
```

Using say `2016-09-27`, but the result it gave me was `8 days` when it really feels like it should be `9 days` (EDT).

Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: Did you try just comparing to the date part of `now()`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I assume this is wrong `datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` as it's giving me a variable type mismatch. I could convert that back to datetime, but I feel like I'm making this too complex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting docs on [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects):

> Only **days, seconds and microseconds** are stored internally. Arguments
>   are converted to those units:
>
> A millisecond is converted to 1000 microseconds. A minute is converted
>   to 60 seconds. An hour is converted to 3600 seconds. A week is
>   converted to 7 days.

So, essentially, your delta is d days, s seconds and m microseconds, but you decided to print only `d` part.

You need to come up with an algorithm to convert `d`, `s` and `m` to "user-friendly" version of delta.

For very simple, maybe-sufficient solution:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
datetime_today = datetime.fromordinal(date.today().toordinal())
d = input('Enter your date: ')
delta = datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d') - datetime_today
print("We'll be {} in {} days".format(d, delta.days))
# We'll be 2016-09-27 in 9 days
```